# In Django, how do I obtain ONLY the file path from a FileField in a form without loading the file into memory?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

For a Django form, I like and need the FileField feature where it allows the user to navigate to a file locally and select it, but on the backend I only want to retain the absolute file path WITHOUT loading the file into memory first.  I'm dealing with files in the 300 million+ records and do not want to do any data storage in memory, only obtain its path on the system.  I tried FilePathField but it mandates pre-specifying a home directory for the files, which would not allow for the navigation feature of FileField.

Comment: Have you tried `obj.file.url`

Comment: `obj.file_field.path`

Comment: Doesn't the "obj" include the data already?  I just want to make sure I'm not storing a 300+ million file as an object prior to getting the path

Answer (score 0):

For files larger than your local settings' FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, uploaded files are automatically stored as TemporaryUploadedFile objects.  To get the path of obj, one must enter `obj.file.path` accordingly.